# How to show grayscale intensity image in its RGB form without merging the channels?

Tags: matlab, rgb

I have a microscope image with three channels (RED, GREEN and BLUE), each channel is unit 16 intensity image. I want to show each channel 
in a subplot (1,3), but in their color form (RGB). I figured it out that with the following command, I can all channels into one RGB image,
but I want to show each channel in one subplot.

```
overlay=cat(3,imadjust(mat2gray(RED)),imadjust(mat2gray(GREEN)),imadjust(mat2gray(BLUE)));
```

Is there anyway to show/convert my intensity grayscale images into RGB format? I also found that following line can shoe each channel in RGB format
but the output image is not adjusted (mostly black) and I cannot adjust it by imadjust command because it's not grayscale anymore.

```
red_IM = cast(cat(3, RED, zeros(size(RED)), zeros(size(RED))), class(RED));
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the histogram plot of the input channels or your red_IM plots so that one can understand the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can divide into separate channels and adjust each of them:

```
im = im2double(imread('peppers.png'));
r = imadjust(im(:,:,1));
g = imadjust(im(:,:,2));
b = imadjust(im(:,:,3));
z = zeros(size(r),'like',r);
r = cat(3,r,z,z);
g = cat(3,z,g,z);
b = cat(3,z,z,b);
subplot(131);
imshow(r);
subplot(132);
imshow(g);
subplot(133);
imshow(b);
```

[image]

Comment: It says: "Index exceeds matrix dimensions."

Comment: i assume it is because your RED, GREEN, BLUE are already separated? try replacing `im(:,:,1)` with `mat2gray(RED)` and so on

Comment: it's really hard to understand your question as a comment. consider marking this answer as accepted and open a new question

Comment: Thanks, I posted a new question.